# LP with negative constraints

Tags: combinatorics, convex-optimization

Please I need guidelines or resources for solving a linear Programming problem which has negative constraints

min 
$
z = 2x_1 - 6x_2-x_3$

s.t

$ 
3x_1 + x_2 + 4x_3\le 6$

$-x_1 + x_2 - 6x_3 \ge -6$

$-x_1 + 3x_2 - x_3 \le 9 $

here is my problem 
$x_1\le -2 , x_2 \ge -3$

how do I change this to get non negative constraints.

Comment: Hello @KwameA, welcome to MSE. In order to type math formulas, use MathJax (see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

Comment: That depends on what you call "standard form".

Comment: getting  non negativity constraints

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Introduce new variables: $z_1=-x_1-2$ and $z_2=x_2+3$.